# How to toggle() a Bool in a non-local func with Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui, func

`animateButton()` works great as a `local func` but when I move it to another swift file to use it on different `Views` it's broken.

I tried `@State/@Binding` and `var isPressed = isPressed` in the non-local func but it doesn't work. I also tried using `inout` but `DispatchQueue` seems to not like it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPressed = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Tap on me")
            .onTapGesture { animateButton() }
        Button("I'm a button", action: {})
            .scaleEffect(isPressed ? 1.20 : 1)
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: isPressed)
    }

    private func animateButtom() {
        isPressed = true
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.20) {
            isPressed = false
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas to make it works as a `non-local func`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `isPressed` as a parameter and you need to make that parameter a `Binding` so changes in the function will update your `@State` property

```
func animateButton(_ isPressed: Binding<Bool>) {
    isPressed.wrappedValue = true
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.20) {
        isPressed.wrappedValue = false
    }
}
```

and change the call to

```
.onTapGesture { animateButton($isPressed) }
```

Comment: Thanks! I over complicated things because I missed `.wrappedValue`.